# FFMPEG to convert swfs - could not find codec parameters

Tags: ffmpeg

I've read mixed reports online about the ability to convert basic SWF files to a video format using FFMPEG.

Can any FFMPEG experts suggest whether there is a way to get this to work reliably?

Using the very simplest of options

```
ffmpeg -i swf1.swf    swf1.mp4
```

I get the following error message

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 17 2015 12:08:40 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.5.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
swf1.swf: could not find codec parameters
```

This happens even with blank swfs!!

Is it possible I am missing a utility or codec for FFMPEG? I am on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg can't decode SWF files that contain "shapes and sprites", whatever this means in the context of Flash. Basically, anything that is more than an actual video stream.

It's an [open wish/feature-request](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1956), but I wouldn't bet on this being implemented anytime soon.

Comment: something else is happening since I get the error even with a blank fla-swf, compiled to earlier flash player versions

Comment: Well,  a blank SWF doesn't have video in it either. I am not much of a Flash expert, but you can't convert anything that's not strictly video+audio.

Comment: I think there is a possible solution using gnash, but have no idea how to use in OSX  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194270/convert-compressed-swf-to-mp4

Comment: Some ideas here: https://github.com/wakoopa/Thwomp